# Saving/Loading GUI with wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I created a UI builder with wxpython meaning I can dynamically create buttons and other widgets then the program will give me the code.

Here is the problem:
How can I let the user save their work? Then load it later, and all the widgets will be back on the screen?

I tried in all the ways I can, even by using `exec()` but I always run into problems.

Can someone please post a example on how to do this? I can't find anything on the internet for this problem.

Comment: Are you using any of the existing tools for this type of thing like wxGlade?  Some example code where you show what you've tried, or what didn't work, would garner much better responses.

Comment: Its on my old computer which is dead, but I used stuff such as exec('wx.Button(...)') and try and recreate all the widgets but nothing comes up. I am hoping someone can post an example that I can look at.

Comment: Also, I am trying to make my own type of wxGlade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use PersistenControls to help with this: http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/main/PersistentControls.html

It's actually included in wxPython now, I think. Probably since 2.8.11. Otherwise, you could use XRC to save it as XML. See the following links for more info:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/XRCTutorial
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/11/wxpython-an-introduction-to-xrc/

Comment: Wow cool, I looked at the example but I don't know how to run it. `main(sys.argv)`? What should I put in there?

Comment: Um, I'm not seeing that example, but I'm guessing you're just passing something on the command line to it in that example, like perhaps the persistent controls saved file? You can ask on the wxPython-users list. The author of this is on there.

Comment: Oh, on the "Download PersistentControls" on xoomer.virgilio.it, there is an example and im not sure how it works.

Comment: Looks like it's just for the demo. You can pass arguments to it to tell it which demo to show or whether or not to show the shell.

Comment: Ok, um do you know an example of what I can put in there

Comment: You just run it from the command line and pass it a method name. I'm not sure which ones they are though. However, you can skip that file for now and just run "PersistentControls.py" to see how it works.

Comment: So this will save the stuff in a file? Which will can be loaded later?

Comment: That's my understanding. You can ask more about it on the wxPython-users list. As I mentioned earlier, the developer behind it is on that group and answers questions and fixes issues almost every day.